# using variables in MDX query

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, mdx

I have a MDX query as follows

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY 
 {[Measures].[Total  Value] } 
 DIMENSION PROPERTIES CHILDREN_CARDINALITY, 
 PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY 
 {      
   CROSSJOIN(    
          {[Supplier].[Supplier Name].[All]},
          {[Warehouse].[Warehouses].[All]},
          {[Buyer].[Business Unit].[All]}
   ),
   CROSSJOIN(
          {[Supplier].[Supplier Name].[All].Children},
          {[Warehouse].[Warehouses].[All].Children},
          {[Buyer].[Business Unit].[All].Children}
   )
} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES CHILDREN_CARDINALITY, 
PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [InventoryAge]
WHERE ( [Calendar].[Report Days].[All Members].&[All].&[WantInReport].&[2].&[20141031] )
```

I am using this query in SSIS package and extract data. I want to pass the value '20141031' (the value is equal to current date) to the query using SSIS package parameters. How can I achieve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDX does not accept parameters.  SSRS has a bit of a hack to work around that, but in the case of SSIS you will need to drop the query into an expression and populate the date from there.

It would look something like this:

```
...
PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [InventoryAge]
WHERE ( [Calendar].[Report Days].[All Members].&[All].&[WantInReport].&[2].&[" 
+ @[User::MyStringDate] + "] )"
```

EDIT:  I should also note that you can find today's date in MDX, use that in a calculated member and cross join that with your query.  Here's is some more information on that: 
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/05/23/how-to-get-the-today-s-date-in-mdx.aspx

Comment: I used getting today's date approach